# How to select every last block with a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

Can you please tell me, is it possible to stylize each last block with the `.type-two` or`.type-one` classes using CSS? Or how can this be solved with the help of JS (for example, add a stylization class)?

```css
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.type {
  display: flex;
}

.type-one {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  color: green;
}

.type-two {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  color: red;
}

.separator {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
  <div class="type type-two">text</div>
  <div class="separator">separator</div>
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
  <div class="type type-two">text</div>
  <div class="type type-two">text</div>
  <div class="separator">separator</div>
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
  <div class="type type-two">text</div>
  <div class="type type-two">text</div>
  <div class="type type-two">text</div>
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is *each last block*? Please add HTML comments in your source example right next to the elements you need.

Comment: Do you mean, each last before a `.separator` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no `:last-of-class` selector in CSS. In JS, tho, the job is quite easy. Please let me know if this solution finds the elements you want to match. If not, please clarify which elements in your HTML you want to target precisely.

```js
const t1 = document.querySelectorAll('.container .type-one');
const t2 = document.querySelectorAll('.container .type-two');

if (t1.length) {
  t1[t1.length-1].classList.add('bold');
}
if (t2.length) {
  t2[t2.length-1].classList.add('bold');
}
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.type {
  display: flex;
}

.type-one {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  color: green;
}

.type-two {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  color: red;
}

.separator {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
  <div class="type type-two">text</div>
  <div class="separator">separator</div>
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
  <div class="type type-two">text</div>
  <div class="type type-two">text</div>
  <div class="separator">separator</div>
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
  <div class="type type-two">text</div>
  <div class="type type-two">text</div>
  <div class="type type-two">text</div>
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
  <div class="type type-one">text</div>
</div>
```